# JViewport won't generate a viewport for JPanel's derived class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, viewport, paintcomponent

I believe JViewport does work with JPanel, but when I build a new class that extends JPanel, it seem as if the JViewport is ignore by the program. I don't know if I do anything wrong, so this is the test I conduct and still get the same result:

```
public class panel extends JPanel
{
    public panel()
    {
        super();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString("Hello World", 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(50,50,100,100);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
    }
}

public class test extends JFrame
{
    private panel p;
    public void init()
    {
        this.setSize(1000, 1000);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

        p = new panel();
        p.setOpaque(false);

        JViewport v = new JViewport();
        v.setViewSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        v.setViewPosition(new Point(2000,2000));
        v.setView(p);
        this.add(v,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public test()
    {
        init();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test t = new test();
    }

}
```

It suppose to show part of the painted JPanel, but the JFrame window just display the whole JPanel. Therefore, I don't know if I did any wrong or JViewport is not built for this purpose. If it is the latter, then it would be great if anyone can suggest a workaround solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `BorderLayout` you're using is causing the viewport, which is placed in the center, to take the entire space inside the frame, since there are no other components in that layout. That's how the `BorderLayout` works.

Thus the viewport is also given a bigger size than defined (the size is overwritten by the layout manager). Since the panel doesn't have a fixed size either, it will also be resized.

In order to change that, either use a different layout manager or set a minimum/maximum size for the viewport and override `getPreferredSize()` for the panel.

As a side note: don't use lower case class names like `panel`.

Comment: +!, seems like when you override `paintComponent(...)` always prefer to override `getPreferredSize()` too :-)